# how i can disable writing /etc/hosts file in MacOS

Tags: macos, hosts

i got some problem, i want to disable [removing, deleting or writing a file] via administrator (sudo user) in MacOS.

for example i want a create a some db of blocked websites without any web filters.

i want disable access for any user in system for hosts file with no control.

Comment: Anything you can do on an admin account, another admin can undo. The only way to prevent that is to not give other users admin accounts.

Comment: i want this disable from my self. i know there is way make something in sudoers file but i realy dont know that realy i need to do

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [SelfControl](https://selfcontrolapp.com) - "SelfControl is a free and open-source application for Mac OS X that lets you block your own access to distracting websites, your mail servers, or anything else on the Internet. Just set a period of time to block for, add sites to your blacklist, and click "Start." Until that timer expires, you will be unable to access those sites--even if you restart your computer or delete the application."

Comment: thanx for app but there is two problems 1. i can delete it 2. its not a permanent

Comment: Did you read up about it? Deleting it does not disable its functionality, though yes, it times out. Timeout is adjustable [massively adjustable] - https://github.com/SelfControlApp/selfcontrol/wiki/Tweaking-Max-Block-Length-and-Block-Length-Interval

Comment: ок i understand, thanx